# Clonar box de inserção de dados de com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, zurb-foundation

Queria fazer funcionar com js(jQuery) a interface abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o framework CSS Foundation para desenvolver este projeto. Porém, não sei como fazer um clone utilizando o jQuery dessa combo onde estão os inputs. Na verdade quero que no momento em que o usuário clique no mais ele dinamicamente adicione mais um linha igual a primeira para dá entrada em mais registros.

O HTML deste registro está abaixo:

```
 <form action="">
    <div class="row box_pergunta">
        <div class="large-8 columns">
           <label>Mensagem:</label>
           <input name="pergunta" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <label>Ordem</label>
            <select name="">
                <option value="antes">Antes</option>
                <option value="depois">Depois</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <input type="button" class="button tiny success btn_remove" value="Remover" style="margin: 1.375rem 0 0 1.5625rem; ">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Já estou utilizando o jQuery no projeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma sugestão de implementação, seria ter um modelo oculto, e quando o usuário clicar no botão clonador, clonar com jQuery e fazer `append` no `form`, exemplo:

**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/jpgcLdog/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
     <div class="small-12 columns text-right">
         <button type="button" class="small tiny alert clonador">Mais</button>
     </div>
    <div class="row box_pergunta hide">
        <div class="small-8 columns">
           <label>Mensagem:</label>
            <input name="pergunta" type="text"/>
        </div>

        <div class="small-2 columns">
            <label>Ordem</label>
            <select name="">
                <option value="antes">Antes</option>
                <option value="depois">Depois</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="small-2 columns">
            <input type="button" class="button tiny success btn_remove" value="Remover" style="margin: 1.375rem 0 0 1.5625rem; "/>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row box_pergunta">
        <div class="small-8 columns">
           <label>Mensagem:</label>
            <input name="pergunta" type="text"/>
        </div>

        <div class="small-2 columns">
            <label>Ordem</label>
            <select name="">
                <option value="antes">Antes</option>
                <option value="depois">Depois</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="small-2 columns">
            <input type="button" class="button tiny success btn_remove" value="Remover" style="margin: 1.375rem 0 0 1.5625rem; "/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.clonador').click(function(){
    //clona o modelo oculto, clone(true) para copiar também os manipuladores de eventos
    $clone = $('.box_pergunta.hide').clone(true);
    //remove a classe que oculta o modelo do elemento clonado
    $clone.removeClass('hide');
    //adiciona no form
    $('form').append($clone);
});
//Para remover
$('.btn_remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.box_pergunta').remove();
});
```

**OBS: Você precisará também manipular os `names` dos elementos do form, dinamicamente, ou utilizar como `array` -> `name="mensagem[]"`**

Comment: Como ponho o botão de cor verde (remover) para funcionar? No caso, remover a linha na qual ele for clicado.

Comment: @Luitame editei a resposta adicionando a função de remover.

Comment: sobre a JS para remover o box ele só funciona no primeiro box da lista. Nos que são clonados o script não funciona. O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: @Luitame você adicionou o `true` como parâmetro no `clone(true)`?

Comment: Tudo funciona normal amigo só não o botão remover

Comment: @Luitame veja no exemplo do http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/jpgcLdog/3 que está funcionando, porém se remover o `true` da função `clone()`, o botão remover não funciona nos elementos clonados, o parâmetro `true` faz com que o manipuladores de eventos também sejam clonados

Comment: Este true do qual se refere está no JS? Onde fica? Dei uma olhada mas não o identifiquem.

Comment: @Luitame Sim, está no JS `$clone = $('.box_pergunta.hide').clone(true);`

Comment: Agora depois que eu recoloquei o True está funcionando lindamente. Obrigada @abfurlan

Answer (score 4):

Você pode clonar o elemento já existente assim:

**Jquery:**

```
$('.clonador').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.box_pergunta:first').clone().appendTo($('form')); // clona o primeiro elemento e adiciona ao final do form
    $('.box_pergunta').last().find('input[type="text"]').val(''); // limpa o campo do novo elemento clonado, pois se já foi preenchido clona junto o valor...

});
$('form').on('click', '.btn_remove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // verifica se tem mais de 1 elemento
    if ($('.box_pergunta').length > 1) 
        $(this).parents('.box_pergunta').remove(); // tem mais de 1, permite remover

});
```

veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/xx3ubyf3/)