# Como fazer um formulário com o número de campos variáveis e inserir esses dados no banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Olá.

Quero criar um CRUD que faça a gestão de palavras e seus sinônimos. Uma palavra tem vários sinônimos (1:N).

Gostaria de uma solução para incluir dinamicamente os inputs, de acordo com a demanda de cada usuário. Por ex, uma palavra a ser cadastrada tem 3 sinônimos, já uma outra palavra tem 10 sinônimos. Aí no primeiro exemplo, 3 campos seriam criados, e no segundo, 10 campos.

Como fazer esse formulário e como inserir esses dados no banco de dados? Estou usando PHP + MySQL.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Eu tentei colocar um formulário com um campo para o usuário digitar o número de sinônimos, depois enviar via Post e mostrar o formulário de cadastro com o número certo de campos. Mas não achei essa solução boa, até pq vou ter que fazer um outro formulário que essa situação irá se repetir mais de uma vez.

Comment: vc tem dúvida em como adicionar mais um `input text` ? e como receber no php?

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma solução para incluir dinamicamente os inputs, de acordo com a demanda de cada usuário. Por ex, uma palavra a ser cadastrada tem 3 sinônimos, já uma outra palavra tem 10 sinônimos. Aí no primeiro exemplo, 3 campos seriam criados, e no segundo, 10 campos.

Comment: Aaaaaah agora sim, acho que todo mundo entendeu o que vc. Para 'duplicar' os inputs é necessario utilizar javascript ou jquery, um detalhe importante o nome desse input teve der colchetes ex:  `'<input type="text" name="sinonimo[]" />` assim o php vai entender que é um array. Você pode fazer um teste simples, crie dois text com o mesmo nome e depois faça o um foreach no php, ex `foreach($_POST['sinonimo'] as $item){ echo $Item.'<br>';}`. Edite sua pergunta e coloque parte do seu comentário nela, vai facilitar para alguem responder.

Comment: Vou editar, obrigada.

Comment: Pode começar com [Clonar box de inserção de dados de com jQuery](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32139/91) e

[Passar variáveis com mesmo name para PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72752/91)

Comment: A pergunta está bacana agora, pode ficar melhor se vc colocar parte do código que fez, se não começou tente :). Vá por etapas, primeiro monte o form e só, depois tente fazer o código que monta os inputs dinamicos funcionar, receber os valores no php e por último gravar no banco.

Comment: Consegui fazer. Muito obrigada rray!